# How can I prevent mold from growing on my bathroom walls?

Tags: bathroom, leak, paint, mold

The humidity in my bathroom is causing mold to grow on the walls.  In addition there was a leak in the roof, that stained the ceiling, and now the ceiling is discolored as well even though the leak was fixed.

Comment: Do you have a bath fan? If yes, is it pulling air?

Comment: Or, as *Defenestrate* suggests, open a window. For the stain, first bleach, then cover with Kilz, shellac or similar waterproof primer, then paint

Comment: Also a quality bath paint, with mildew and mold inhibiters. Kilz is great for the primer and now they have top coat paint.